# Wrong data format for store loadData method ExtJS

Tags: json, extjs, store, dataformat, loaddata

I want to call JSON data as much as the amount of data in the store. Here is the code:

```
storeASF.each(function(stores) {
    var trano = stores.data['arf_no'];
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        results: 0,
        url: '/default/home/getdataforeditasf/data2/'+trano+'/id/'+id,
        method:'POST',
        success: function(result, request){
            var returnData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
            arraydata.push(returnData);

            Ext.getCmp('save-list').enable();
            Ext.getCmp('cancel-list').enable();

        },
        failure:function( action){
            if(action.failureType == 'server'){
                obj = Ext.util.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error!', obj.errors.reason);
            }else{
                Ext.Msg.alert('Warning!', 'Server is unreachable : ' + action.response.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
    id++;
});
storeARF.loadData(arraydata);
```

StoreASF contains data[arf_no] which will be used as a parameter in Ajax request url. StoreASF could contain more than one set of the object store, so looping is possible. For every called JSON data from request would be put to array data, and after the looping is complete, I save it to storeARF with the loadData method.

The problem is, my data format is wrong since loadData can only read JSON type data. I already try JSON stringify and parse, but couldn't replicate the data format. Any suggestion how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `Ext.util.Json.decode()`, normalize the data in `success()` method using your own logic. For example:

```
success: function (response) {
             console.log(response);
             var myData = [];
             Ext.Array.forEach(response.data, function (item) {
                 myData.push({
                     name: item.name,
                     email: item.email,
                     phone: item.phone
                 });
             });
             store.load();
}
```